# Developing custom action center shorcuts

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

since info about this matter is scarce I would like to start a topic asking if anyone knows if its possible to develop custom shorcuts for the new Action Center in windows phone 8.1. We already know we can choose from a list of pre defined shorcuts, but addtional info about making your own would be appreciated (links, personal experience, API knowledge, etc)

Comment: Oh, sorry about the misunderstanding. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API or option for a 3rd party app to feature in the Action Center list of shortcuts at this time.